# MongoDb If and or statement Issue

Tags: mongodb

```
"$redact": {
   "$cond": {
     "if": {
       "$eq": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$messages.type", -1 ] }, "A" ]
     },
     "then": "$$KEEP",
     "else": "$$PRUNE"
   }
}
```

On the above code, i need to  add 2 more condition in if statements but not able to add them.
i.e  (messages.type = 'A' or messages.type = 'D') && (messages.sender=61)

Please help

Comment: please react to/accept your other question and I will help!

Comment: please help now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$cond` with `$and` like this:

```
{$cond : [{$and : [{$eq : [1,1]},{$eq : [2,2]},{$eq : [3,3]}]},"yes","no"]}
```

returns "yes"

```
{$cond : [{$and : [{$eq : [2,1]},{$eq : [2,2]},{$eq : [3,3]}]},"yes","no"]}
```

returns "no"

edit:

As per the query in the OP (note this is untested):

```
"$redact":{
    $cond : [
        {
            $and : [
                {
                    $or : [
                        {
                            $eq : [
                                "$messages.type",
                                "A"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $eq : [
                                "$messages.type",
                                "D"
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $eq : [
                        "$messages.sender",
                        61
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you answer in term of message.type and message.sender

Comment: you just have to substitute the 1,1 2,2 and 3,3 with the things you want to compare.

Comment: what about redact keep and prune

Comment: we need to matcha against last elem as shown by { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$messages.type", -1 ] }, "A" ] but its fine.